# How to get object argument from npm script (NodeJS + TypeScript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, command-line-interface

I want to pass an object via NPM script like

```
  "update-user-roles": "ts-node user-roles.ts {PAID_USER: true, VIP: true}"
```

My function picks up the object but keeps adding additional commas so it's not updating the user correctly. How do I receive the object as is?

```
async function updateUserRoles(roles: any) {
    const userID = await getAuth().then((res) => res.uid);
    updateUser({
        userID: userID,
        fields: {
            roles: {
                roles
            },
        }
    })
    console.log(`User roles successfully added: ${roles}`)
}

const rolesString = JSON.stringify(process.argv.slice(2))
updateUserRoles(JSON.parse(rolesString))
```

I get the following message:

```
User roles successfully added: {PAID_USER:,true,,VIP:,true}
```

Comment: That's certainly odd, you can make your life easier by using a simple library like _minimist_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get any of these answers to work, finally got a solution using the following:

The script:

```
"ts-node user-roles.ts '{\"PAID_USER\": true, \"VIP\": true}'"
```

Parse the object string back into an object using JSON.parse and pass to function:

```
const objArgStr = process.argv[2];

if (!objArgStr) {
  console.error('No argument provided.');
  process.exit(1);
}

const objArg = JSON.parse(objArgStr);
console.log('Object argument: ', objArg);

updateUserRoles(objArg)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you got comma `,`  is because Nodejs will split command-line arguments at whitespace. The `process.argv` array will be like this:

```bash
[
  '/home/lindu/workspace/project/node_modules/.bin/ts-node',
  '/home/lindu/workspace/project/index.ts',
  '{PAID_USER:',
  'true,',
  'VIP:',
  'true}'
]
```

> The `process.argv` property returns an array containing the command-line arguments passed when the Node.js process was launched.

**Option 1. Pass a JSON string**

```bash
$ npx ts-node ./index.ts '{"PAID_USER": true, "VIP": true}'
```

`index.ts`

```
console.log(process.argv);
console.log(JSON.parse(process.argv.slice(2)[0]));
```

Output:

```
[
  '/home/lindu/workspace/project/node_modules/.bin/ts-node',
  '/home/lindu/workspace/project/index.ts',
  '{"PAID_USER": true, "VIP": true}'
]
{ PAID_USER: true, VIP: true }
```

**Option 2. Pass a string and parse it to a JSON string.**

```bash
npx ts-node ./index.ts '{PAID_USER: true, VIP: true}'
```

`index.ts`:

```
console.log(process.argv);

const arg = process.argv.slice(2)[0];
const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eval('(' + arg + ')')));
console.log(obj, typeof obj, obj.PAID_USER, obj.VIP);
```

Output:

```
[
  '/home/lindu/workspace/project/node_modules/.bin/ts-node',
  '/home/lindu/workspace/project/index.ts',
  '{PAID_USER: true, VIP: true}'
]
{ PAID_USER: true, VIP: true } object true true
```

**Option 3. Use [minimistjs](https://github.com/minimistjs/minimist) package.**

Comment: Option 1 didn't work for me but Option 2 does, thanks.

Comment: @George It should work, please double-check it I updated the answer

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work, you can't have them quotes in an NPM Script and JSON Parse gives error in ```TypeScript Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)```

Comment: Option 2 has randomly stopped working ```const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eval('(' + arg + ')')));
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'```

Comment: I can't get Option 3 to work and their documentation is non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

We can use double quotes to wrap the object.

```
"update-user-roles": "ts-node user-roles.ts \"{\\\"PAID_USER\\\": true, \\\"VIP\\\": true}\""
```

After that:

```
async function updateUserRoles(rolesString: string) {
  const roles = JSON.parse(rolesString);
  const userID = await getAuth().then((res) => res.uid);
  updateUser({
    userID: userID,
    fields: {
      roles: roles
    }
  });
  console.log(`User roles successfully added: ${JSON.stringify(roles)}`);
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed, you are not passing in a real object as a parameter, but a string that is not a valid json.

First, the parameter must be wrapped and escaped (\"{...}\") so that it is not split up by the blanks.

Here then come two helper functions. One to read out the parameter using a key (myObject). And the second to make an object out of the string (fake json).

```
"update-user-roles": "ts-node user-roles.ts myObject=\"{PAID_USER: true, VIP: true}\""
```

And here is the minimal JavaScript functionality.

```
const args = process.argv.slice(2).reduce((acc, arg) => {
    let [k, v = true] = arg.split('=');
    acc[k] = v;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(args) // { myObject: '{PAID_USER: true, VIP: true}' }

const parseJSON = obj => Function('"use strict";return (' + obj + ')')();

const myObject = parseJSON(args.myObject); // { PAID_USER: true, VIP: true }
```

Your function call would then be

```
updateUserRoles(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Node.js treats arguments as string and splits them by whitespace, so `roles` looks something like this:

```js
[
  "{PAID_USER:",
  "true,",
  "VIP:",
  "true}"
]
```

Also, it's not a JSON string. You have to turn that to JSON and wrap in quotes so Node.js will count the entire thing as one argument:

```
ts-node user-roles.ts "{\"PAID_USER\": true, \"VIP\": true}"
```

*Don't forget to escape quotes in string!!*

In `user-roles.ts`:

```js
const rolesString = process.argv.slice(2)[0]
updateUserRoles(JSON.parse(rolesString))
```

Because `process.argv.slice(2)` returns an Array, you'll need to get the first argument. You also don't need `JSON.stringify()`.
It can be simplified like this:

```js
updateUserRoles(JSON.parse(process.argv.slice[2]))
```